# Sharepoint list not recording correct approver details in Power Automate Flow

Tags: list, sharepoint, power-automate

I have a Sharepoint List and a 2 stage power automate approval process based on this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/sequential-modern-approvals

Everything is working as expected except that when I view the history any of the list items all of the edits by the approvers are shown as being modified by me rather than created by me and then modified by the approvers?

I'm content that v1.0 of any of the items was modified by me since I created them but the approvals were all done by someone else via the flow - I need that fact to be shown in the item history for audit purposes but the default "Modified By" field in the list is not available to me in the flow design?

Can anyone suggest a fix for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The edits to the list are done under the identity of the connector in the approval flow (ie you). You cannot change the 'Modified By' of SharePoint List item.

Consider creating a column like 'Approver' and setting that based on the approver. You could also consider creating a System Account and having your flow use that credential/connection - then when looking at history everyone can see that the system account did the update (ie automation).

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to this and somewhat confused that Sharepoint/Power flow has this as default behaviour? It would defeat the whole point of the process for all approvers actions to be mis-recorded as the "system" did it but if I can have a separate field that records the identity of the approver them that might work.  Why this isn't an obvious issue to the micorsoft folks who created the example is also bemusing (the article has other errors/omissions so I shouldn't be surprised).

Comment: Think of the implications if it was possible to edit Modified By. One could make a terrible edit and then blame it on someone else. This is no different than any other datasource.